# Can’t read siteMetadata object from gatsby-config.js multiple queries GrahQL - Gatsby ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to read the content of siteMetadata object I defined in `gatsby-config.js` file, from multiple queries at once using GraphQL.
I have this error:

```
error  'siteMetadata' is not defined  no-undef
```

My JS file

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        slug
        title
        logo
        about
        language
      }
    }

    site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
          description
          author
        }
      }
  } 
`
```

and I call

```
{siteMetadata.title}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `gatsby-config.js` you should have an object called `siteMetadata` within the same structure than you are querying:

```
module.exports = {
      siteMetadata: {
        title: `Some title`,
        description: `Some description`,
        author: `Some author`,
      },
  plugins: [...]
}
```

Then, on your page, you have to access to `data` variable, which stores all the information queried.

```
export const YourPage= ({ data }) => {
  const yourTitle = data.site.siteMetadata.title;
  return ...
}
```

The problem is that you are accessing directly to `siteMetadata` which is not defined yet, your information is stored inside `props.data.site.siteMetadata`, destructuring `data` as a `prop`, it saves you one step.

Comment: I've edited my answer with how to access queried data.